# Ruby child class update parent class variable

Tags: ruby

I am trying to update the parent class variable from the child class. This is what I have

```
class Dog
  def initialize
    @breed = []
  end

  def show
    puts "#{@first_name} of breed #{@breed}" ### <- Changed
  end
end

class Lab < Dog

  attr_reader :first_name, :i
  def initialize
    super ### <- Added
    @first_name = "good dog"
    @i = 1
  end
  def add
    @breed << @i
    @i += 1
  end
end
```

As you can see, I have a `@breed` variable in the parent class, which the child class has access to. But when I update the `@breed` variable from the child class and call the same variable from the parent class it does not show the update values. How can I do that?

```
irb(main):172:0> d = Dog.new
=> #<Dog:0x00005607908130d8 @breed=[]>
irb(main):173:0> l = Lab.new
=> #<Lab:0x000056079081add8 @breed=[], @first_name="good dog", @i=1>
irb(main):174:0> d.show
 of breed []

irb(main):175:0> l.show
good dog of breed []

irb(main):176:0> l.add
=> 2
irb(main):177:0> l.show # inherited variable got updated
good dog of breed [1]

irb(main):178:0> d.show # parent array did not get updated?
 of breed []

irb(main):179:0>
```

Calling `d.show` returns an empty array, but calling `l.show` returns the filled array. I would like my parent class also return the filled array. Is this possible? What am I missing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your ask about class variables, but there are no class variables anywhere in your code.

Comment: What is the `@breed` variable supposed to do? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

`d` and `l` in your example are *absolutely different objects*, having nothing in common. That’s not how inheritance works.

There would be a brief example of using the instance variable from parent class.

```rb
class Dog
  def initialize
    @breed = []
  end
  def add
    puts "Dog: #{@breed}"
  end
end

class Lab < Dog
  def initialize
    super ### <- @breed is now declared
  end

  def add
    puts "Lab 1: #{@breed}"
    @breed << :ok
    super
    puts "Lab 2: #{@breed}"
  end
end

Lab.new.add
#⇒ Lab 1: []
#⇒ Dog: [:ok]
#⇒ Lab 2: [:ok]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, at least not without some (unadvisable) hacking.

You are missing the distinction between **classes** and **instances**. There can be a hierarchy of classes, as you created with `Dog` and `Lab`, but the instances you create from these classes don't have a hierarchical relationship. The (instance) variables, like `@breed`, are private to each instance and each instance has its own copies.

In other words: There is no "*parent* array", only an array which has been declared in a parent class.

It looks like you want a collection of `Dog` instances. The right place would a variable *outside* of the `Dog` class.

```rb
class Dog 
  attr_reader :first_name

  def initialize(name)
    @first_name = name
  end

  def show
    puts "#{first_name} of breed #{self.class.name}"
  end
end

class Lab < Dog
  def initialize
    super('good dog')
  end
end

class Schnauzer < Dog
end

class BlackLab < Lab
end
```

Notice that I moved `first_name` from `Lab` to `Dog`, because `Dog#show` already uses it and it makes no sense to declare it in a sub class.

You can use this class hierarchy to collect multiple instances in an array which is stored outside of the class hierarchy:

```rb
breeds = []
breeds << Dog.new('some dog')
breeds << Lab.new
breeds << Dog.new('another dog')
breeds << Schnauzer.new('yet another')
breeds << BlackLab.new

breeds.each do |dog_instance|
  dog_instance.show
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
some dog of breed Dog
good dog of breed Lab
another dog of breed Dog
yet another of breed Schnauzer
good dog of breed BlackLab
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dog
  def initialize
    puts "self in Dog#initialize = #{self}" 
    @breed = []
  end
  def show
    puts "#{@first_name} of breed #{@breed}"
  end
end
```

```
class Lab < Dog
  attr_reader :first_name, :i
  def initialize
    super
    @first_name = "good dog"
    @i = 1
  end
  def add
    @breed << @i
    @i += 1
  end
end
```

Let's create an instance of `Lab` and examine its instance variables:

```
sue = Lab.new
  #=> #<Lab:0x000059195710eec8 @breed=[], @first_name="good dog", @i=1>
  # displays: self in Dog#initialize = #<Lab:0x000059195710eec8>
sue.instance_variables
  #=> [:@breed, :@first_name, :@i]
sue.first_name"
  #=> "good dog" 
sue.i
  #=> 1 
sue.instance_variable_get(:@breed)
  #=> []
```

Notice I had to use [Object#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) to obtain the value of `sue`'s instance variable `@breed` because no getter had been created for that instance variable.

You say you wish to "update the parent class variable from the child class". Firstly the parent class, `Dog` has no class variables or instance variables (sometimes referred to as *class instance variables*). I assume you mean the instance variable `@breed` that is associated with each instance of `Dog`. In fact, it appears that one would not likely create an instance of `Dog`; that `Dog` has been created only to define methods and instance variables that are to be used by subclasses of `Dog`. Nevertheless, let's create an instance of `Dog`:

```
bob = Dog.new
  #=> #<Dog:0x0000591956ffd4a8 @breed=[]> 
  # displays: self in Dog#initialize = #<Dog:0x0000591956ffd4a8>
bob.instance_variables
  #=> [:@breed] 
bob.instance_variable_get(:@breed)
  #=> []
```

Let's also change the value of `@breed` for this instance:

```
bob.instance_variable_get(:@breed) << "pug"
  #=> ["pug"]
```

Now let's add a method `get_iv` to `Lab` to get the value of the instance variable `@breed` of an instance of `Dog`. Think about the information that must be passed to this method. It needs to know which instance of `Dog` we are concerned with (as different instances may very well have different values for their instance variables), and for that instance, which instance variable we are interested in. (Here there is but one, but let's make it general so that we could add instance variables to `Dog`'s instances.)

```
class Lab
  def get_iv(instance, instance_variable)
    instance.public_send(:instance_variable_get, instance_variable)
  end
end
```

See [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send). So we could now write:

```
sue.get_iv(bob, :@breed)
  #=> ["pug"]
sue.get_iv(bob, :@breed) << "collie"
  #=> ["pug", "collie"]
```

Sure enough, we have accomplished the task:

```
bob.instance_variable_get(:@breed)
  #=> ["pug", "collie"]
```

But wait! Now let's create a completely unrelated class and an instance of it.

```
class Bird
  def initialize
    @type = ["canary"]
  end
end
```

```
tweetie = Bird.new
  #=> #<Bird:0x0000591956ffee98 @type=["canary"]>
```

Next, let `sue` get and alter the value of `tweetie`'s instance variable `@type`:

```
sue.get_iv(tweetie, :@type)
  #=> ["canary"] 
sue.get_iv(tweetie, :@type) << "robin"
  #=> ["canary", "robin"]
```

and confirm they've been changed:

```
tweetie.instance_variable_get(:@breed)
  #=> ["canary", "robin"]
```

The point is that the instance method we must add to `Lab` requires two pieces of information:

- the instance whose instance variable's value is to be obtained; and
- the name of the instance variable.

This has nothing to do with the fact that `Lab` is a subclass of `Dog`! Therefore, to get or set the value of an instance variable of an instance of `Lab`'s superclass is no different than getting or setting the value of an instance variable of *any other class*.